# TwitterApi: How do i get the endpoint of the app?

Tags: twitter, twitterapi-python

I subscribed twitter api for `Search Tweets: Full Archive  /  Premium`

In the yaml file I have to enter the access details.

```
account_type: premium
  consumer_key: xxx
  endpoint: ????????????????????????????
  consumer_secret: xxx
  bearer_token: xxx
```

I got all the keys and tokens. But what is the ```endpoint`` that I have to use? Where do I get that from ?

I'm using `searchtweets` library to access the api.

Answer (score 0):

This library and API need you to provide the full URL to the API endpoint, because this is dependent on your options (30-day or full archive, and development environment name).

In your case, it would be something *like*

`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/tweets/search/fullarchive/dev.json`

Note that everything after `/search/` depends on your setup:

- You've already said that you want to use full archive, so I filled that in.
- The last piece `dev.json` depends on your environment name from the premium dashboard. You might have named this differently to "dev". Under Products->Premium->Dev environments, look for the "Dev environment label". That's what you append, plus `.json`.

So for me, I have premium full archive with an environment called "dev", so my endpoint ends in `dev.json` (as above). Just as another example, for premium 30-day search, my environment is called "development" and the URL endpoint is:

`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/tweets/search/30day/development.json`